# Faster alternative to Try and Except in Python

Tags: python, c

[Problem:](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/train/python)

> Complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.
>
> Notes:
>
> - Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits will be included.
> - Performance needs to be considered

I could solve this problem in C. Since I am interested in learning Python, I tried to do this in Python also, but unfortunately got timeout error. I do not know how to solve it in Python the same way I did it in C.

So, please tell me how can I do this in Python efficiently, preferably with same or better technique I used with C.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool scramble(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    // store number of occurrences of each character in str1 to arr
    int arr[26] = { 0 };

    while (*str1) {
        arr[*str1 - 'a'] += 1;
        str1++;
    }

    // check if each character of str2 is in arr
    while (*str2) {

        if (arr[*str2 - 'a'] >= 1)
            arr[*str2 - 'a'] -= 1;
        else
            return false;

        str2++;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My Python code which is probably correct but times out:

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    text = list(s1)

    for char in s2:
        try:
            text.remove(char)
        except ValueError:
            return False

    return True
```

Also, if you find something wrong with my C code, please inform me.

PS: sorry for my English.

Comment: Why not start by using the same way to find a solution in python as you are in C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think you are very new to Python. You could find more about collection : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html&ved=2ahUKEwj9wICRqfPoAhVo73MBHRcBAq8QFjAAegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw2mS2EUGTioSwy05lVk67KH

***defaultdict*** is a method of ***collections*** package/library that initialize the data structure with some initial value.
Example:

```
import collections
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
print(counter[ANY_KEY])
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
0
{ANY_KEY: 0}
```

So, since we have given `defaultdict(int)` i.e ***int*** , defining any key will always initialise with value given in brackets

```
import collections
def scramble(s1, s2):
    counter = collections.defaultdict(int)

    for char in s1:
        counter[char]+=1
    for char in s2:
         counter[char]-=1
         if counter[char] <= -1:
             return False
    return True
```

Comment: Yes, I am indeed new to Python :) Am I right that you are using the same method I used in C? Could you explain what `collections.defaultdict(int)` does?

Comment: ***defaultdict*** is a method of ***collections*** package/library that initialize the data structure with some initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't `Try` `Except` it's that your algorithm is quadratic in complexity, which will start to fall apart as the strings get really large. For each character in `s2` you need to look through `s1`. The code wars site runs test for strings of  up to 600000 characters. An O(n^2) algorithm is going to be a problem there.

Here's an option that will be slower on small strings, but will scale better to large ones:

```
from collections import Counter

def scramble(s1, s2):
    c1 = Counter(s1)
    c2 = Counter(s2)
    return all(c1.get(k, 0) >= s for k, s in c2.items())
```

It works by making a single pass through each string to get the counts and then one more pass to test. It passes all the test on the codewars site.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize complexity could be a issue before you pointed out that they are testing with input as large as 600000 characters.